# Automatically reload data in shinyapp

Tags: reactive, shinyapps

I created a small app that gets data from an online google sheet document and shows graphs generated from the data.
I would like the app to automatically reload the table every minute.

I have trobles to implement the `reactivePoll()` function , but maybe this is not even the correct way to go?
This is my first ShinyApp and I spent quite a lot of time to find a solution...
I would really appreciate some help! :)

My code for the server.R looks like this:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    
    sheet_id <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/example"
    gs4_auth("myemailaddress@gmail.com")
    df<-read_sheet(sheet_id)
        
    pt1 <- ggplot(df, aes(Timestamp, Temp_C))+
        geom_line(color="darkred", size=1.2)+
        theme_minimal()+
        xlab("time")+
        ylab("temp")
   
    output$plot1 = renderPlot({pt1})    
}
)
```

ui.R

```
fluidPage( navbarPage("Title",
               tabPanel("Page 1"),
               tabPanel("Page2", "Temperatur",plotOutput("plot1"))
    
    )
)
```